# passport.js not working on without mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

my app.js is

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');


app.set('views', __dirname+'/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({secret : 'somthing'}));
app.use(flash());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.locals.message = req.flash();
    console.log(res.locals);
    next();
});
app.use(require('./controller/router'));

// Default Controller Come Here
app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Running');
})
```

router.js is

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.use('/', require('./home'));
router.use('/login', require('./login'));
router.use('/user', require('./user'));

module.exports=router;
```

passport.js (inside of config folder)

```
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

var User = require('../model/users');


passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    done(err, id);
});


passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done){
        if(username == "test@test.com") 
        /* hardcore check username and password */
        {
            if(password=="123")
            {
                var result = { id : 1, fullname : "james", username : "jamesjoel"};
                console.log("Success");
                return done(result, true);
            }
            return done(null, false, { message : "Incorrect Passwordtttt"});
        }
        return done(null, false, { message : "Incorrect Username and password"});

    }

));
module.exports=passport;
```

and finaly my login.js controller is

```
var passport = require('../config/passport');
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();


    router.post('/',  passport.authenticate('local', { 
            successRedirect: '/user',
        failureRedirect: '/login',
        failureFlash: true 
      })
    );


    router.get('/', function(req, res){
        console.log(req.flash());
        res.render('login', { msg : req.flash()});
    });

    module.exports=router;
```

but when i send correct username and password it show in console "success" and show [Object Object] and successRedirect not working infact i wrote somthing on .serializeUser() and .deserializeUser() its also not showing on console....
so please help me for this .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `done` is a callback and it takes first argument as an error. But in your case after success still you are passing value as error try to make it null like this  `return done(null,result, true)`

```
if(password=="123"){
    var result = { id : 1, fullname : "james", username : "jamesjoel"};
    console.log("Success");
    return done(null,result, true);
 }
```

Comment: you are right but now its showing "err is not defined" and successRedirect working proper....?

Comment: it's syntax error, can you please check where are you getting this error and did you define it before using somewhere?

Comment: Happy to help you :)